# Utility for converting Shift-JIS encoded files to UTF-8 encoded files

Tags: software-rec, encoding, utf-8, ascii, shift-jis

My client has a ton of Japanese text files which are encoded in Shift-JIS.

They need a utility which can convert these files to UTF-8.

Ideally the tool would offer both command-line and interactive options.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: this would be better suited on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) (or [iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm), as the case may be).

Comment: iconv <original.file> -f SHIFT-JIS -t UTF8 -c -o <converted.file>

Answer (score 0):

[ConvertZ](http://www.bumpersoft.com/Education-and-Science/Languages/ConvertZ-12649.htm) is also a good free alternative

> ### ConvertZ is a Chinese/Japanese code converter.
>
> Features:
>
> - Supported file (plain text) and clipboard conversion among the following encodings: big5, gbk, hz, shift-jis, jis, euc-jp, unicode big-endian, unicode little-endian, and utf-8.
> - Batch files conversion
> - Preview before actual conversion.
> - Auto-update the charset in meta tag if specified in HTML docs.
> - Auto-fix mis-mapped Big5/GBK characters.
> - Change encoding of mp3's ID3v1/v2 tag among big5, gbk, shift-jis, unicode and utf-8.

[image]

[image]